# $scope.myVariable not updated in controller for angular-ui bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

In my view I have an input, a span and a button like so:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myTemplate.html">
  <input type="text" ng-model="phoneNumber">
  <span>{{ phoneNumber}}</span>
  <input type="button" ng-click="click()">
</script>
```

When typing in the textbox, the content of the `span` updates as expected reading. But when clicking the button, `phoneNumber` has not updated inside the controller:

```
app.controller('myPopopCtrl', ['$scope', '$modalInstance',
  function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
      $scope.phoneNumber= '';    

      $scope.click = function() {
        alert($scope.phoneNumber); // alerts only ''
      };
```

Is there some newbe mistake you can make in angular which makes stuff not updating on the `$scope` inside a controller?

Are there some $scope issues with the [angular-ui modal](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) I need to be aware of?

**Edit:**

It seems like `phoneNumber` gets created in 2 scopes. One time in the scope at the blue arrow which where `phoneNumber: ''` and once in the child scope at the red arrow. The view uses the `phoneNumber` in the child scope and the controller uses the `phoneNumber` in the parent scope...

[image]

Why are two scopes created?

Comment: Where is the click method defined?

Comment: click method is defined inside the popupController, (I updated the question to clarify)

Comment: Then the better options for you would be to pass a object instead of string as string assigment creates a new string in the child scope. Create something like `$scope.phone={number:null}` and pass it along.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`ng-include` creates a new scope. So pass a object instead of string

`$scope.phone={number:null}`

The template then looks like

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myTemplate.html">
  <input type="text" ng-model="phone.number">
  <span>{{ phone.number}}</span>
  <input type="button" ng-click="click()">
</script>
```

Look at this [wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) to understand the issues with prototypal inheritance.

Comment: would never have guessed those issues existed in angular.. Thank you :)

Comment: This was hours upon hours of heartbreak trying to figure out why my modal wasn't working until I stumbled upon this, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and after a few experiments I've settled on writing

```
<input type="text" ng-model="$parent.phoneNumber">
```

This way input is bound to the blue scope, which is exactly what you wanted.

Other way is to initialise phoneNumber with a true-ish value. Try `$scope.phoneNumber= '123';` - worked fine for me.

Angular seems to walk up the scope tree looking for an attribute to bind to. If nothing's found - it binds to the inner-most scope, red scope in your pic.
As other answer suggests - this red scope is created by ng-include, as a child of controller's $scope.